# How to make an image stretchable like it's being viewed on a image viewer?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a personal website that is just an image (for now till I have web dev classes)
As the title says, I want to make an image stretchable like it's being viewed on an image viewer. When I view the page there's the image, but I could scroll down to see the rest of an image and I don't want that. When I say "like it's being viewed on an image viewer" I mean have black bars on sides like here:

[image: here]

I have no idea where to start nor how to search for it, that's why I'm asking here.
Here's [the source code](https://github.com/LukaTV939/lukatv.lol) of my site rn (it's atrocious)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show some code here in your question. Also, [never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: As for the functionality you're describing... If I were to attempt this, my initial approach would be to figure out how to style an image to (1) take up 100% of the window height and no more, and (2) keep its aspect ratio (either automatically or by re-calculating it in code).  I'd try to apply this either to an `<img>` element or to a `<div>` with an image as a `background`.

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could make a small bit of your code available as demo instead of us looking through a github repo. That said, you're either looking for [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) or [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). For both, `cover` will stretch the img or bg until the smallest side fills the container, and `contain` will stretch the img or bg until the largest side fills the container. Cover will fill the whole area, and contain will scale until it hits an edge.

Comment: Stretchable, as in you want to stretch the image and deform it somehow?

Comment: Please make this a code snippet instead of linking to your git repo.

Comment: Looks like I only needed to add object-fit: contain; on img and set height to 100%.
Also, I'm sorry for poorly making this question, I didn't know this site is super serious when it comes to coding, should've just ask for this on Reddit

Answer (score 0):

I've added some JavaScript code within the  tag in the HTML file to enable opening an image when it's clicked, and I've also implemented functionality for a cancel icon to close the image. I'm making an effort to enhance the design of your website as well.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@800&display=swap');
    </style>
    <head>
        <title>Luka tv</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1><span></span></h1>
        </div>
        <img class="unshow" src="webpage.png">
        <p class="unshow">&#10006;</p>
    </body>

    <script>
        const bodyTag = document.querySelector("body"),
        imgTag = document.querySelector("body img"),
        cancelTag = document.querySelector("body p");

        imgTag.addEventListener("click",(elm)=>{
            if (!imgTag.classList.contains("show")){
                imgTag.classList.add("show");
                imgTag.classList.remove("unshow");
                bodyTag.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                cancelTag.classList.remove("unshow");
                cancelTag.classList.add("show");  
            }
        })
        
        if (!imgTag.classList.contains("show")){
                cancelTag.addEventListener("click",() => {
                    if (!cancelTag.classList.contains("unshow")){
                        cancelTag.classList.add("unshow");
                        cancelTag.classList.remove("show");
                        imgTag.classList.add("unshow");
                        imgTag.classList.remove("show");
                        bodyTag.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }
                    else{
                        cancelTag.classList.remove("unshow");
                        cancelTag.classList.add("show");
                    }
                })    
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    color: white;
    height:100vh;
}

* {
    border: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100vh; 
    width: 100%; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 {
    /* background-color: rgba(30,30,30,.6); */ 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 69px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-right: 21px;
    /* padding: 2rem; */
}

span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* phone styles */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    body {
        background-color: #000069;
    }

    h1 span::before{
        content: "Hello mobile user, please rotate your screen. Thanks";
    }

    img {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .container {
        position: relative;
    }
}

/* tablet styles ig */

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (min-height: 210px) {
    body {
        background-color: #000096;
    }

    h1 span::before{
        content: "Hello tablet user, please rotate your screen. Thanks (also I'm not centering this text, fuck you)";
    }
}

/* wysi styles */

@media (min-width: 727px) and (max-width: 727px) and (min-height: 211px) and (max-height: 211px) {
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }

    h1 span::before{
        content: "WYSI";
    }
}

/* tablet styles again */

@media screen and (min-width: 728px) and (max-height: 212px) {
    body {
        background-color: #000096;
    }

    h1 span::before{
        content: "Hello tablet user, please rotate your screen. Thanks (also I'm not centering this text, fuck you)";
    }
}

/* desktop styles */

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    h1 span::before{
        content: "";
        background-image: url(webpage.png);
    }

    #container {
        border: 0px;
        min-height: auto;
    }

    img {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
}

img {
    width: 50%;
    border:5px rgb(255, 221, 0) solid;
    transition: all ease .4s;
}
img:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
    border:5px rgb(255, 255, 0) solid;
    scale: 102%;
}
img.show {
    border:none;
    transition: none;
}
img.show:hover {
    opacity:100;
    border:none;
    scale:100%;
}
img.show{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
p{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 3%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
p.unshow{
    display: none;
}
p.show{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is an answer to the question